# grunt.option('force', true) not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

Based on the [`grunt.options` documentation](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.option#grunt.option), I was expecting to be able to programmatically start a Grunt task with the `force` option turned on like so:

```
var grunt = require('grunt'); 
grunt.option('force', true); 
grunt.tasks(['test']);
```

I expected this to be equivalent to running `grunt test --force` from the command line. But the `force` option isn't being applied:

```
Warning: Task "karma:unit" failed. Use --force to continue.
```

How can I programmatically start a Grunt task with the `force` option enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish what I was trying to do in a different way.  Instead of setting the `force` option programmatically, I'm now using the [`grunt-force`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-force) plugin to set `force = true` for the rest of my tasks:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', 'Builds the app.', ['force:on', 'typescript:main', ...etc]);
```

I'll gladly accept a more direct answer to my original question if anyone knows a solution.